# C# create simple xml file

Tags: c#, xml

How can I create a simple xml file and store it in my system?

Comment: This is vague, easily googleable, and you've offered no information or suggestion that you've tried to do this yourself.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You could use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx):

```
new XDocument(
    new XElement("root", 
        new XElement("someNode", "someValue")    
    )
)
.Save("foo.xml");
```

If the file you want to create is very big and cannot fit into memory you might use [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx).

Comment: +1 @Darin I just want to add that the example given outputs the xml to the console, but if you use the Save method of the xdocument it will allow you to save it to your pc.

Comment: Funny, with all the brackets, it looks (and feels) almost like LISP.

Comment: Great, way better, shorter and more readable than using `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Wonderful solution.

Answer (score 46):

I'd recommend serialization,

```
public class Person
{
      public  string FirstName;
      public  string MI;
      public  string LastName;
}

static void Serialize()
{
      clsPerson p = new Person();
      p.FirstName = "Jeff";
      p.MI = "A";
      p.LastName = "Price";
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
      x.Serialize(System.Console.Out, p);
      System.Console.WriteLine();
      System.Console.WriteLine(" --- Press any key to continue --- ");
      System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You can further control serialization with attributes.
But if it is simple, you could use XmlDocument:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class GenerateXml {
    private static void Main() {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        doc.AppendChild(docNode);

        XmlNode productsNode = doc.CreateElement("products");
        doc.AppendChild(productsNode);

        XmlNode productNode = doc.CreateElement("product");
        XmlAttribute productAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
        productAttribute.Value = "01";
        productNode.Attributes.Append(productAttribute);
        productsNode.AppendChild(productNode);

        XmlNode nameNode = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        nameNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("Java"));
        productNode.AppendChild(nameNode);
        XmlNode priceNode = doc.CreateElement("Price");
        priceNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("Free"));
        productNode.AppendChild(priceNode);

        // Create and add another product node.
        productNode = doc.CreateElement("product");
        productAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
        productAttribute.Value = "02";
        productNode.Attributes.Append(productAttribute);
        productsNode.AppendChild(productNode);
        nameNode = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        nameNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("C#"));
        productNode.AppendChild(nameNode);
        priceNode = doc.CreateElement("Price");
        priceNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("Free"));
        productNode.AppendChild(priceNode);

        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
}
```

And if it needs to be fast, use XmlWriter:

```
public static void WriteXML()
{
    // Create an XmlWriterSettings object with the correct options.
    System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "    "; //  "\t";
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
    settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    using (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create("data.xml", settings))
    {

        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("books");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("book");
            writer.WriteElementString("item", "Book "+ (i+1).ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    } // End Using writer 

}
```

And btw, the fastest way to read XML is XmlReader:

```
public static void ReadXML()
{
    using (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create("http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"))
    {
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if ((xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "Cube"))
            {
                if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
                    System.Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.GetAttribute("currency") + ": " + xmlReader.GetAttribute("rate"));
            }

        } // Whend 

    } // End Using xmlReader

    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And the most convenient way to read XML is to just deserialize the XML into a class. 
This also works for creating the serialization classes, btw.
You can generate the class from XML with [Xml2CSharp](https://github.com/msyoung/XmlToCSharp): 
https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: There are quite a few more ways than two and XDocument is generally preferred to XmlDocument post 2.0