# How to create an XML file from this c# class?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to create an XML file from the following c# class and vice-verse. How can i do this?

```
public class Settings
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string ParentId { get; set; }

    public List<Settings> SubSettings { get; set; }

    public bool IsRoot
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummmm... what are you asking here?

Comment: I am asking what should be the best XML structure for the c# class given in my question!

Comment: why down-vote?? can anyone please explain me??

Comment: I downvoted your question because it's unclear what you're asking. The "XML structure" of a class doesn't mean anything. You can use a serializer that will output some XML or you can choose a different XML layout - whatever you like. There's no XML structure that "should be" used for your class.

Comment: @xxbbcc i got your point, thanks i really don't know about XmlSerialization!

Comment: Your question wasn't about XML serialization. If you reword the question to be more precise (and describe what you're trying to do), I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @user1740381 Best in what way?  Most compact?  Or easier to configure using default `XmlSerializer` behavior?

Comment: @xxbbcc i edited my question, now remove your downvote please!

Comment: when I googled your title I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094940/c-sharp-create-simple-xml-file) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604982.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172873.aspx) and [this](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/) and [this](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmlwriter-class/) and [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-create-xml.htm) ...

Comment: .. and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/244234/how-to-create-xml-document-programatically-in-csha) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/create-xml-in-C-Sharp/) and [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML/ProgrammaticallycreatinganewXMLdocument.htm) and [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-create-xml.htm). This is **the first page on google**. With the title of your question. Please research before posting.

Comment: -1 because you show no research effort. If you **have** done research do include it in the question and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize a class in C# using `XmlSerializer` like this:

```
var s = new Settings()
{
    Id = "id",
    Name = "name",
    ParentId = "parentId",
    Value = "value",
    SubSettings = new List<Settings>()
    {
        new Settings() 
        { 
            Id = "subId", 
            Name = "subName", 
            ParentId = "subParentId", 
            Value = "subValue", 
            SubSettings = new List<Settings>() 
        }
    }
};

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));

string fileName = "C:\\test.xml";

using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    serializer.Serialize(fs, s);
}
```

This is the result that I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>id</Id>
  <Name>name</Name>
  <Value>value</Value>
  <ParentId>parentId</ParentId>
  <SubSettings>
    <Settings>
      <Id>subId</Id>
      <Name>subName</Name>
      <Value>subValue</Value>
      <ParentId>subParentId</ParentId>
      <SubSettings />
    </Settings>
  </SubSettings>
</Settings>
```

You can then deserialize it back to an object like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));

Stream fs = new FileStream("C:\\test.xml", FileMode.Open);

Settings settings = (Settings)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```