# C# create XML file from Datatable with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datatable, linq-to-xml

I am new to XML and want to create XML document from datatable

I have a DataTable with following data:

[Database Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYqo4.png)

I need to create an XML file from above DataTable data as below:

```xml
<Root>
    <DB>
        <ORACLE>
            <name1>
                   <CONNECTION_STRING>connection1</CONNECTION_STRING>
                   <COMMAND>SELECT * FROM table</COMMAND>
            </name1>
            <name2>
                   <CONNECTION_STRING>connection2</CONNECTION_STRING>
                   <COMMAND>SELECT * FROM table</COMMAND>
            </name2>        
            <name3>
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>connection3</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND>SELECT * FROM table</COMMAND>
            </name3>        
        </ORACLE>
        <SQL>
            <name4>
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>connection4</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND>SELECT 1</COMMAND>
            </name4>
            <name5> 
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>connection5</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND>SELECT 1</COMMAND>
            </name5>
            <name6>
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>connection6</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND>SELECT 1</COMMAND>
            </name6>

        </SQL>
        <MYSQL>
            <name7>
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>connection7</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND>SELECT 1</COMMAND>
            </name7>
            <name8>
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>connection8</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND>SELECT 1</COMMAND>
            </name8>
            <name9>
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>connection9</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND>SELECT 1</COMMAND>
            </name9>
        </MYSQL>
    </DB>
    <SERVER>
        <SERVER>
            <Server1>
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>192.168.0.1</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND></COMMAND>
            </Server1>
            <Server2>
                    <CONNECTION_STRING>192.168.0.2</CONNECTION_STRING>
                    <COMMAND></COMMAND>
            </Server2>
        </SERVER>
    </SERVER>
</Root>
```

I tried the following but it is not giving me the expected result:

How can I iterate through datatable rows to create XML document?

Comment: Are you sure that is the xml you want to create? You are just making it difficult to consume by using different element names (name1, name2, etc.) for each item.

Comment: yes, i need the xml in that format. It's a work request...

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094951/10646316).

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("CONNECTION_STRING", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("CONNECTION_TYPE", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("COMMAND", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection1", "ORACLE", "SELECT * FROM table"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection2", "ORACLE", "SELECT * FROM table" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection3", "ORACLE", "SELECT * FROM table" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection4", "SQL", "SELECT 1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection5", "SQL", "SELECT 1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection6", "SQL", "SELECT 1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection7", "MYSQL", "SELECT 1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection8", "MYSQL", "SELECT 1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "connection9", "MYSQL", "SELECT 1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "192.168.0.1", "SERVER", "" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "192.168.0.1", "SERVER", "" });

            string xml = "<Root><DB></DB></Root>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement db = doc.Descendants("DB").First();

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("CONNECTION_TYPE"));

            foreach (var type in groups)
            {
                XElement newDb =  new XElement(type.Key);
                db.Add(newDb);

                int count = 0;
                foreach (var conn in type)
                {
                    count++;
                    XElement newConn = new XElement("name" + count);
                    newDb.Add(newConn);
                    newConn.Add(new XElement("CONNECTION_STRING", conn.Field<string>("CONNECTION_STRING")));
                    newConn.Add(new XElement("COMMAND", conn.Field<string>("COMMAND")));

                }
            }


        }
    }
 
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this way.

```
           var connection = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("CONN_TYPE"));

            // Generate the root element
            var root = new XElement("Controlli", new XAttribute("xmln:sxsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),

                connection.Select(
                    d => d.GroupBy(r => (ChildType: r.Field<string>("CHILD_TYPE"), ConnType: r.Field<string>("CONN_TYPE"))).Select(
                        deptNo =>
                                       new XElement(deptNo.Key.ChildType,
                                       new XElement(deptNo.Key.ConnType,
           d.Select(
               r =>
                    new XElement(r.Field<string>("CONN_NAME"),
                        new XElement("CONNECTION_STRING", r.Field<string>("CONNECTION_STRING")),
                        new XElement("COMMAND", r.Field<string>("COMMAND")
                        ))))))));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).